# Laravel hasMany returns 0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to create a relationship between a Post and the Likes that it has. I followed the video tutorial on Laracasts exactly besides my class names, but mine didn't work. [Laracast Video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/8) So I searched for a bit. Most people that have problems with this have a return of null or get an error. When I do it mine returns 0.

Code that returns 0:

```
>>> $post = App\Post::first();
>>> $post->likes;
=> 0
```

But if I try this I am able to get the value.

```
>>> $post->likes()->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#656
     all: [
       App\Like {#657
         id: 2,
         post_id: 1,
         user: "robert",
       },
     ],
   }
```

My Post Class:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class Post extends Model
{
  public function likes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
  }
}
```

My Like Schema:

```
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('user');
        });
```

Posts Table Record:

```
id   => 1
text => Lorem Ipsum
user => Joe
```

Likes Table Record:

```
id => 1
post_id => 1
user => robert
```

What can I do to fix this?

### EDIT:

I kept playing around with my code and so far it looks like `$post->likes()->get()` *was* the right way of doing it. This will fetch the instance of the class and from there I can do thing like `$post->likes()->get()->username` to see who liked the post.
Then if I want to display how many likes are on a single post I can do something like this. `$post->likes()->count()`

Answer (score -1):

To get how many likes a post has you have to count the query results like this:

```
$post->likes()->count();
```

This should return `1`.

If you want to just fire `$post->likes` and get the number of likes you will need to define a getter in your Like model (not advised).

Something along the lines of this

```
public function __get($key)
{
    if ($key === 'likes') {
        return $this->likes()->count();
    }

    return parent::__get($key);
}
```

Comment: I will defiantly use this.
But what does `$post->likes` do by itself?

Comment: @CriticalTheWizard IIRC, it's the same as calling `$post->likes()->get()`

Comment: @Doom5 I thought that is what it did, but why is mine returning different things?